# Sql: show data in a single row instead of different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a sql query which is as below

```
SELECT ryot_code, ryot_name, variety_group, SUM(total_area)
FROM field_survey_trn
WHERE unit_code = '01'
  AND season_cntrl = 20
  AND crop_type_code NOT IN (11,12)
  AND ryot_code != 0
GROUP BY ryot_code, ryot_name, variety_group;
```

**output**

[image]

In **variety_group** column I am getting different variety code for same ryot_code in different lines.

My question is, how can I write a query, using which I can get all type or ** variety_code** for a same grower in a single row like below image

[image]

Comment: Why no output for 000100006, 000100009 etc?

Comment: @jarlh I think he just didn't include everything.  So this is just a pivot question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped the query in your original question in an outer query which performs a pivot on the `variety_group` column:

```
SELECT t.ryot_code, t.ryot_name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.variety_group = 10 THEN t.theSum ELSE 0 END) AS '10',
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.variety_group = 20 THEN t.theSum ELSE 0 END) AS '20',
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.variety_group = 30 THEN t.theSum ELSE 0 END) AS '30'
FROM
(
    SELECT ryot_code, ryot_name, variety_group, SUM(total_area) AS theSum
    FROM field_survey_trn
    WHERE unit_code = '01' AND season_cntrl = 20
        AND crop_type_code NOT IN (11,12) AND ryot_code != 0
    GROUP BY ryot_code, ryot_name, variety_group
) t
GROUP BY t.ryot_code, t.ryot_name
```

Comment: I think there will be problem if `variety_group` values are increase from 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 .... and so on.

Comment: Agreed.  This answer assumes that he has a small and fixed number of variety groups.  Let's wait for the owner of the question to also comment.

Comment: had to remove semi colon after ** GROUP BY ryot_code, ryot_name, variety_group**, I guess it was not letting execute rest of sql (I am using mysql).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  Because your query was so complex I didn't have the time to create a Fiddle for it.

Comment: Yes I had limited number of variety groups. There is another option **Pivot** to solve it

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in SQL using `PIVOT`.

```
SELECT * FROM

(
   SELECT ryot_code, ryot_name, variety_group, total_area
FROM field_survey_trn
WHERE unit_code = '01'
  AND season_cntrl = 20
  AND crop_type_code NOT IN (11,12)
  AND ryot_code != 0

) as my_name

PIVOT

(

    SUM(total_area)

    FOR [variety_group] IN ([10], [20], [30])
) piv1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of result as 
it would be preferred if you design it in single column of **variety group** with comma separated values like 10, 30 for **ryot_code** 00010004

If you like that suggestion then it can be done using below query

```
`SELECT group_concat(variety_group separator ',') INTO var_grp, 
    ryot_code, ryot_name, SUM(total_area)
 FROM field_survey_trn
 WHERE unit_code = '01'
 AND season_cntrl = 20
 AND crop_type_code NOT IN (11,12)
 AND ryot_code != 0;`
```

Hope this works as expected